# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, stereo-3d

I am trying to get the depth map of two stereo images. I have taken the code from [this documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20190203045746/https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_depthmap/py_depthmap.html).

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "depth.py", line 9, in <module>
    stereo = cv2.createStereoBM(numDisparities=16, blockSize=15)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createStereoBM'
```

My code is:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

imgL = cv2.imread('tsukuba_l.png',0)
imgR = cv2.imread('tsukuba_r.png',0)

stereo = cv2.createStereoBM(numDisparities=16, blockSize=15)
disparity = stereo.compute(imgL,imgR)
plt.imshow(disparity,'gray')
plt.show()
```

I entered the Python line interpreter, and wrote the following code:

```py
import cv2
help(cv2)
```

There is no function called `createStereoBM` in `cv2`.

Is the code wrong in the link provided at the top? I am using Python 2.7.3 in Ubuntu 12.04.
Is it possible that the code is meant for Python 3 and above?

Please help.

Comment: the code you're using is from the opencv master/3.0 branch. (and yes, you have to use cv2.createStereoBM() there instead of cv2.StereoBM() ) for looking at further examples, [use the 2.4 branch](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/2.4/samples/python2) instead .

Comment: I had to use cv2.StereoBM_create() for 3.0.0-beta version of OpenCV

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this function instead

```
stereo = cv2.StereoBM(cv2.STEREO_BM_BASIC_PRESET,ndisparities=16, SADWindowSize=15)
```

You can find documentation for this function [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.1/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereobm-stereobm)

Comment: But not works with >= 3.x. This works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43661169/1797782

Answer (score 12):

`cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=16, blockSize=15)`

Try it. My opencv version is 3.2.

If you want to find any function working in opencv, you can try this

> > 1. import(cv2)
> > 2. help(cv2)

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

import cv2

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

imgL = cv2.imread('l.png',0)

imgR = cv2.imread('r.png',0)

stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=16, blockSize=15)

disparity = stereo.compute(imgL,imgR)

plt.imshow(disparity,'gray')

plt.show()
```

try to use this code is your using the code from open-cv documentation

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the example from the trunk (aka devel) documentation. if you aren't using trunk version, try to find an example for your correct version.