# Both input images must have CV_8UC1 in function error

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy

I plan to do a stereo image from the tutorial [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_depthmap/py_depthmap.html#py-depthmap), but the compiler reports errors with `cv2.createStereoBM`, I found out it was the problem of OpenCV version.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702945/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute) to change `cv2.createStereoBM` into `cv2.StereoBM`. It works well, but the following code:

```
disparity = stereo.compute(frame0,frame1)
```

shows error:

> Both input images must have CV_8UC1 in function cv::findStereoCorrespondenceBM

Can anyone help me with this?

The environment is Python 2.7, OpenCV 2.4.11.

My code is:

```
cap0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
while (cap0.isOpened() and cap1.isOpened()):
    ret0, frame0 = cap0.read()
    frame0_new=cv2.cvtColor(frame0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ret1, frame1 = cap1.read()
    frame1_new=cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


    stereo = cv2.StereoBM(cv2.STEREO_BM_BASIC_PRESET,ndisparities=16, SADWindowSize=15)

    disparity = stereo.compute(frame0,frame1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use your frames converted to single channel, i.e. of type `CV_8UC1`:

```
disparity = stereo.compute(frame0_new, frame1_new)
```

Comment: thank you so much! Too stupid error of me! btw, the CV_8UC1 is a name of image type?

Comment: CV_<number_of_bits_per_channel><Unsigned/Signed/Float>C<number_of_channels> it's an OpenCV flag to describe matrix type, channels, etc... CV_8UC1 is just a single channel matrix of uint8 (or uchar)

Comment: really appreciate the explanation.

Comment: Wait, where did frame0_new and frame1_new come from?

Comment: @ComputerScientist check again the question, it was edited out by the OP.