# Both input images must have CV_8UC1 in function 'cv::StereoBMImpl::compute'

Tags: python, opencv, stereo-3d

I am capturing images from my drone camera over wifi. The following is my code in python using OpenCV functions (other OpenCV tasks are working well with the same input images) and I am getting the error

```
Both input images must have CV_8UC1 in function 'cv::StereoBMImpl::compute'

            if frameno == 1:
                imagen = cv2.cvtColor(numpy.array(frame1.to_image()), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) 
                frameno = frameno+1
                print frameno
            if frameno == 0:
                imageo = cv2.cvtColor(numpy.array(frame1.to_image()), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
                frameno = frameno+1
                print frameno
            stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities = 16, blockSize = 17)
            disparity = stereo.compute(imagen,imageo)
```

I am getting the error in `stereo.compute` function. 
Well I am using the same `frame1.to_image()` for generating input frames to other OpenCV functions and it works fine there but when I started trying out for stereo disparities code it is generating an error I and do not know why. I have seen another thread here
[CV_8U1 error stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068257/both-input-images-must-have-cv-8uc1-in-function-error) but that guy has not faced a problem after he used the converted images but I am facing an error. Please let me know what I should do here.

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed that the color conversion should be COLOR_RGB2GRAY. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For copy and pasters:

```
grayLeft = cv.cvtColor(left, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayRight = cv.cvtColor(right, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

stereo = cv.StereoBM_create(numDisparities = 16, blockSize = 17)
disparity = stereo.compute(grayLeft, grayRight)

plt.imshow(disparity,'gray')
plt.show()
```