# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'createStereoBM'

Tags: python, opencv, stereo-3d

I tried to run code from the OpenCV docs for creating a disparity image from left and right stereo images, but it gives me an error. Here is the code I ran.

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

imgL = cv2.imread(r'D:\left.png', 0)
imgR = cv2.imread(r'D:\right.png', 0)

stereo = cv2.createStereoBM(numDisparities=16, blockSize=15)
disparity = stereo.compute(imgL, imgR)
plt.imshow(disparity, 'gray')
plt.show()
```

I am getting an error in the line

```
stereo = cv2.createStereoBM(numDisparities=16, blockSize=15)
```

And this is the error

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'createStereoBM'
```

I have tried many other solutions previously listed on stackoverflow, github, and other forums but none of them seemed to work.

The link to the OpenCV documentation can be found [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_depthmap/py_depthmap.html)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `stereo = cv2.StereoBM(numDisparities=16, blockSize=15)`?
i.e. remove the `create` prefix from the method name

Comment: @wpercy Yes, I have tried that. In that case, I get error in the next line `disparity = stereo.compute(imgL, imgR)`. The error reads `TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'StereoMatcher' or its derivative)`

Comment: How about `cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=16, blockSize=15)`?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule This seemed to work for me! Thanks a lot! I had actually tried this method before but didn't get the results I was hoping for that time. So this time I changed the value of `numDisparities` to `64` and got the result I wanted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702945/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [oluwafemi-sule](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5189811/oluwafemi-sule) mentioned in the comments you just need to use `cv2.StereoBM_create` instead of `cv2.createStereoBM` and it will work

[image]